# Return few variables of a class in scala

Tags: class, scala, return

I have a controller in my scala program in spring MVC framework that returns value to response body.The return type is the class type. Could someone tell me how to display only few values of the class.As of now, When i execute the code, it displays the values of all the variables in the class. If a variable doesnt have value it displays null. But I just require selected variables of the class to be displayed.

```
@Entity
class User_details{
@BeanProperty var user_id : String = _;
@NotNull
@BeanProperty var email : String = _;
@NotNull
@BeanProperty var password : String = _;
@BeanProperty var name :String = _;
}



def getmeth(user:User_details):User_details={   
user
}
```

It displays the o/p as

```
 {
    "user_id": "12345",
    "email": "alex@gmail.com",
    "password": "shhh",
    "name": null
     }
```

Now, I need the o/p to display all the details except the name.

```
{
"user_id": "12345",
"email": "alex@gmail.com",
"password": "shhh"   
 }
```

Could you please help me with this??

Answer (score 0):

Are you returning json?  If so then whatever library you're using will probably provide a way to filter out fields with null values; for example, if this were Play Json and I had a [JsObject](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.1/api/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsObject.html) then I'd do something like

```
def filterNulls(json: JsObject): JsObject = {
  JsObject(json.fields.filter(kvPair => kvPair._2 != JsNull))
}
```